# Not able to set env with character '='in SMF solaris

Tags: solaris, smf

svccfg -s network/inetd setenv UMEM_DEBUG default,firewall=1

this command is not working. I need to set an environment variable to the inetd service with "=" as a character in environment variable value.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your command correctly you want to set the value of `UMEM_DEBUG` to `default,firewall=1`

You can do this interactively

```
svccfg -s network/inetd 
svc:/network/inetd> setprop start/environment=astring ("UMEM_DEBUG=default,firewall=1")
svc:/network/inetd> listprop start/environment
start/environment    astring    UMEM_DEBUG=default,firewall=1
svc:/network/inetd>
```

Comment: quotes shouldn't be part of UMEM_DEBUG env value.

Comment: Firewall is an hidden option in umem

Comment: @suresh: Have a look at the changes I made

Comment: @suresh; please post corrections as a comment, Iain will edit them into his answer if he thinks they are appropriate. Thank you!